# Problrm in sdk manager

Tags: android, eclipse

When I start SDK Manager in eclipse android then nothing will open and will show the message like

```
[2014-08-24 16:01:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
[2014-08-24 16:01:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the path specified
[2014-08-24 16:01:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] java_exe was unexpected at this time.
```

So Please HELP me to start SDK MANAGER.

Answer (score 0):

May be you relocated your SDK folder to a path different from the one in Eclipse path so this error appeared so make sure of SDK Location in the following path Window > Perferences > Android it must contains the right SDK folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1) :** Download the Android Development toolkit from [**Developers site**](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

**Step-2) :** Unzip the SDK to a location in your PC

ex: I have added my sdk into  location `D:\android_sdk\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk`

**Step-3) :** I your eclipse go to `Window > Perferences >`

**Step-4) :** Point the right path in `sdk location`

[image]